OV13850 camera sensor
I am using OV13850 camera sensor module with the RK3399 board.
Is it possible to get the full resolution crop mode 1080p stream from OV13850?
OR At least 1080p window/ROI stream from OV13850 at 60 FPS?
Is 30 FPS limit here?

According to the manual  (page 22) it support 2112x1568 at 60 fps. And as subformat 1080p EIS 2112x1188 60fps by cropping.

